# Custom commerce order_id

Tags: rules, commerce, payment-gateways

Where is the default commerce order_id set and how can i change it to my custom order number?

I am using the Commerce Order Counter module to set a custom order number.
drupal.org/project/commerce_order_counter

The problem i have is the order_id that is passed to paypal is the default commerce order_id and not my custom order number.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change order id as other functionalities are dependent on it.But you can change order number before saving order to shopping cart status by using  hook_commerce_order_presave($order).

```
function example_commerce_order_presave($order) {
   if ($order->status == 'cart') {
   $order->order_number = 'new order number;
   commerce_order_save($order);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [hook_commerce_order_presave](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.api.php/function/hook_commerce_order_presave/DC)($order)

which has options to alter the order object before saving.
Maybe you can add your custom code inside this function an alter the order id.